# Django Smart Select JQuery Conflict

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am trying to use Django smart selects as part of my website development. I first noticed that when the field, the Smart select field was working as it should in the form however it was conflicting with my jQuery templates.

I tried to add a line in settings.py

JQUERY_URL = False

However when I added this setting the template, it worked correctly but the smart select field was blank

[image: Smart Select Field coming up blank]

The Jquery I'm using in my templates is:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is because of the JQuery I used.  I updated it to the below and then it worked.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js